# Angular 5 Animation runs for multiple list items inside ngFor

Tags: angular

I have a ***productsItems*** array which is coming from a parent element via Input() and I would like to add the animation on each element when it's removed.

However, the animation is running for all the elements. Is it possible to run the animation only on the removed item.

**animation.ts**

```
 import { trigger, state, animate, transition, style, sequence } from 
'@angular/animations';

export const SlideToggleAnimation =
trigger('slideState', [
    state('show', style({
        opacity: 1,
        visibility: 'visible'
    })),
    state('hide', style({
        opacity: 0,
        visibility: 'hidden'
    })),
    transition('show => hide', animate('300ms ease-out')),
    transition('hide => show', animate('300ms ease-in')),

    transition('* => void', [
        style({ height: '*', opacity: '1', transform: 'translateX(0)', 'box-shadow': '0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)' }),
        sequence([
            animate(".25s ease", style({ height: '*', opacity: '.2', transform: 'translateX(20px)', 'box-shadow': 'none' })),
            animate(".1s ease", style({ height: '0', opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(20px)', 'box-shadow': 'none' }))
        ])
    ]),
    transition('void => *', [
        style({ opacity: '0', transform: 'translateX(20px)' }),
        sequence([
            animate(".2s ease", style({ opacity: '1', transform: 'translateX(2px)' })),
        ])
    ])
])
```

I detect the remove button actions via output() and use it to determine the state of the animation. 
Is this happening because the ***productItems***, since it's updating every time after the list is changed.

**main.component.ts**

```
<li class="shopping-cart__item" *ngFor="let product of productsItems" 
[@slideState]="product.isRemoved ? 'hide' : 'show'" 
(@slideState.start)="animStart($event)" 
(@slideState.done)="animEnd($event)">
....
<app-remove-button [productId]="product._id" (isRemoved)="onRemove($event)" appDeleteIconHover></app-remove-button>
</li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to do this via trackBy.

**main.component.ts**

```
trackByProductId(index: number, product: any): string {
    return product._id;
}
```

**main.component.html**

```
<li class="shopping-cart__item" 
 *ngFor="let product of productsItems;  
  trackBy:trackByProductId" [@slideState]="product">
   ...
   ...
 </li>
```